# Error Occurs : "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Reportviewer.Winforms Version=10.0.0.0" while generating Report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, reporting-services, .net-3.5

I created an application using .net 4.0 in which there were two forms.
First form accepts the data from the user and the second form contains the report viewer control which generates the bill.

The image of the Data Entry form is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci0tv.png)

The image of the generated bill is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siCM2.png)

As I wan to run this application on different computer systems,I made this application compatible to .net 3.5 framework.

It was converted successfully but the this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3hNX.jpg) occurs when I click on the Print Button.

Please help me how to tackle this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is .net 3.5 service pack 1 installed at PC where this error comes ?

Comment: Yes Sir, Whenever I change the PC to run the application, first I install the framework 3.5 then I attempt to run the exe .. @Coder

Comment: Seems you just have .net 3.5 without SP1, try to uninstall it and install 3.5 SP1 from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442 Also, check this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1768946.aspx/1

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sir, I am trying your suggested way.. @Coder

Comment: Should I also run the ReportViewer.exe to each PC wherever I want to run my application? @Coder

Comment: Generally it gets installed with visual studio but for _Could not load file or assembly_ error you need to manually install it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir. It's working perfectly after installing the ReportViewer.exe @Coder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26768/discussion-between-riyaz-kalva-and-coder)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install **[ReportViewer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442)** to PCs where this error come.

Comment: I have created the package in which my application's exe files, the .net framework 3.5 sp1 and the ReportViewer.exe are stored. Do I need add anything more to run this application to other PC without installing Visual Studio? @Coder

Comment: I think you don't need anything more.